# Cannot enable dynamically generated select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a system where several selects are dynamically populated with an ajax call to a servlet.  The options are generated on the servlet, which determines which options are enabled or disabled.

One one select, I need to enable one or more of the options that are marked disabled.  However, I can't seem to enable them after the ajax call.  At first I thought it might be an async problem, but I handled that and I still cannot enable them.

I've tried .prop("disabled", false), tried .attr("disabled", false), and tried .removeAttr("disabled").  None of those have worked.

The HTML for the call.  The options for selEditRun are also dynamically generated, with the value corresponding to the database id of the "run":

```
    <select id="selEditRun" onchange="populateEditRun()">
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function populateEditRun() {
    var id = $('#selEditRun').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'TCAUServlet',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            formType: 'getRun',
            id: id
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (responseText) {
            responseText = $.parseJSON(responseText);
            var deputies = responseText.officersAssigned;
            //other field actions removed
            var tmpDate = $('#txtEditRunDateTime').val();
            $.when(updateDisablesLists(tmpDate)).done(function () {
                enableOptions(deputies);
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("An error occurred.  Error:  " + status + ", " + error);
        }
    });
}

function updateOfficerWithDisables(d) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'TCAUServlet',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {formType: "getOfficersWithDisables",
            date: d
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#selEditRunDeputies').html(responseText);
            //other select population removed
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("An error occurred.  Error:  " + status + ", " + error);
        }
    });
}

function enableOptions(deputies) {
    var tmpArray = [];
    $.each(deputies, function (name, value) {
        tmpArray.push(value.id); //get option values that are to be enabled
        $("#selEditRunDeputies option[value='" + value.id + "']").attr("disabled", false); //set to enabled
    });
    $('#selEditRunDeputies').val(tmpArray);  //set the appropriate field(s) selected)
}

function updateDisablesLists(val) {
    var d = convertDatePickerToDate(val);
    updateOfficerWithDisables(d);
}
```

And finally, on the servlet:

```
private String getOfficersWithDisables(HttpServletRequest request) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    String htmlString = "<option value=''>&nbsp;</option>\n";
    List<Officer> officerList = TCAUDatabaseUtil.getOfficers();
    String dateString = request.getParameter("date");

    Date d = sdf.parse(dateString);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    for (Officer officer : officerList) {
        boolean hasRun = !(TCAUDatabaseUtil.getRunName(d, officer.getId()).equals(""));
        boolean hasAppt = TCAUDatabaseUtil.hasAppt(d, officer.getId());
        boolean isReserveDay = (dayOfWeek == convertTCAUDayToCalendarDay(officer.getRd1()) || dayOfWeek == convertTCAUDayToCalendarDay(officer.getRd2()));
        boolean isAssigned = !(TCAUDatabaseUtil.getAttendanceEvent(d, officer.getId()).equals(""));
        boolean isDisabled = (hasAppt || hasRun || isReserveDay || isAssigned);

        htmlString += "<option value='" + officer.getId()+ "'" + (isDisabled?" disabled":"") + ">" + officer.getDisplayName() + "</option>";
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

I realize this is a lot of code to post (having been yelled at on here for posting too much code), but I don't know where I'm screwing up at.

Comment: Why is your `datatype: 'html'` when you're parsing `json` as a response? Also if value is `null` or "", what response do you get from your AJAX call?

Comment: @Twisty:  that ajax call returns one "run" object.  I think "datatype: html" is a copy-n-paste error, but it still worked so I didn't notice it.  Value won't be null or "" unless someone goes into the database manually and starts deleting stuff.

Comment: If I understand the operations, the user selects a date, this will in turn enable or disable a number of options in the select element, such that they cannot be assigned to that date. Is this working along the right path?

Comment: You also have `<option value=''>&nbsp;</option>` as an option in your select element; therefore, the value `''` could be passed to as an `id` unless I am reading this wrong. It would be really helpful to see an example of the resulting HTML or AJAX data.

Comment: @Twisty:  Close...the user selects a run which contains a date.  The selEditRunDeputies is then updated via ajax.  Options for individuals unable to be assigned are disabled, but the original individuals assigned (which are disabled because of being assigned to this "run") need to be enabled so one or more can be reselected for the same run.  Did that make sense?

Comment: @Twisty:  the <option value=''> is just a placeholder.  The select is populated before any selection is made, and validated before submission.

Comment: Where is `deputies` defined?

Comment: @Twisty:  In the success: of populateEditRun(). I must have deleted it when I was removing all the other fields being populated, but just edited it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out the logic of what you were trying to explain. Not a big deal, the issue comes down to enabling and disabling options. I think your issue is related to formatting.

Consider the following:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option disabled>2</option>
</select>
```

This is valid yet is also shorthand. The `option` element has the following attributes ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)):

```
Attribute  Value     Description
---------------------------------
disabled   disabled  Specifies that an option should be disabled
label      text      Specifies a shorter label for an option
selected   selected  Specifies that an option should be pre-selected when the page loads
value      text      Specifies the value to be sent to a server
```

So what is more valid is the following:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option disabled="disabled">2</option>
</select>
```

Now you can call `.prop()` on this and set `disabled` to `true` or `false` using this method.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2xj18jk9/

**ASP**

```
private String getOfficersWithDisables(HttpServletRequest request) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    String htmlString = "<option value=''>&nbsp;</option>\n";
    List<Officer> officerList = TCAUDatabaseUtil.getOfficers();
    String dateString = request.getParameter("date");

    Date d = sdf.parse(dateString);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    for (Officer officer : officerList) {
        boolean hasRun = !(TCAUDatabaseUtil.getRunName(d, officer.getId()).equals(""));
        boolean hasAppt = TCAUDatabaseUtil.hasAppt(d, officer.getId());
        boolean isReserveDay = (dayOfWeek == convertTCAUDayToCalendarDay(officer.getRd1()) || dayOfWeek == convertTCAUDayToCalendarDay(officer.getRd2()));
        boolean isAssigned = !(TCAUDatabaseUtil.getAttendanceEvent(d, officer.getId()).equals(""));
        boolean isDisabled = (hasAppt || hasRun || isReserveDay || isAssigned);

        htmlString += "<option value='" + officer.getId()+ "'" + (isDisabled?" disabled='disabled'":"") + ">" + officer.getDisplayName() + "</option>";
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function enableOptions(deputies) {
  var tmpArray = [];
  $.each(deputies, function(name, value) {
    tmpArray.push(value.id); //get option values that are to be enabled
    $("#selEditRunDeputies option[value='" + value.id + "']").prop("disabled", false); //set to enabled
  });
  $('#selEditRunDeputies').val(tmpArray);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the same result.  However, I wanted to make sure that I was getting valid id's, so I put  alert(value.id) as the first line inside the loop in enableOptions.  To my surprise, everything worked as expected. I took the alert out, and it stopped working.  Could the loading in updateDisablesList not be finished even with the when...done in there?

Comment: I suspect that it is. Could look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/